# Blender and Gloss

Tags: materials

I am trying to give my rig a little gloss on the suit and gloss on the eyes. Whenever I give it a glossy or glass modifier it picks up too much of the environment texture.

What it looks like right now
[image: What it looks like right now]

What I want it to look like
[image: What I want it to look like]

Some help would be much appreciated and if you need more information on what I want or more pictures I'm glad to send more

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you are using so far for shaders? You may want to consider trying the principled bsdf with roughness map to control the glossyness, in general glossy surfaces are less rough than non-glossy.

Comment: @Sazerac I've added what nodes I'm using (I'm not really good at materials yet) top two are for the main suit and bottom for the eyes

Comment: By using the Alpha as the mix factor for the shader, you are going to get a lot of gloss shader in the mix. Unless the alpha of the image is necessary to eliminate the shader showing up on geometry when it isn't needed, you don't need to plug the alpha in like that. Try disconnecting that and then adjusting the mix factor manually or using a layer weight node to control the mix factor while also adjusting the roughness of the gloss node.

Comment: Should I use fresnel or facing in the layer weight node? and any recommended starting values? Here is also what I am at so far:https://imgur.com/a/x7dVoiz